# return-to-libc attack

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, glibc

I was trying to attempt at return-to-libc buffer overflow attack for my Computer Software Security assignment. As far as my understanding goes, we can do these kind of attacks regardless of stack protection measures such as `canaries` and `non-executable stack`. This is because the `libc` functions do not reside on the stack and we just need to shift our program's control flow by overwriting the return address with the `libc function address` and passing suitable arguments. This figure seems to summarize the procedure I guess.
[image: return-to-libc-demo]
 What my doubt is, according to the figure for second part, is the stack frame given for the `libc` function or is it just for a function defined in the user's program itself? I am not able to figure out the need of `fake_ret`. Can't we just overwrite the return address of our function by overwriting `EIP` with the address of say `unlink` and the arguments can be placed in the user's function buffer which can be used to pass to the `unlink` function?
 Please note that by the use of user's (something), I aim at pointing to (something) which is defined by the user himself/herself in his/her program. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a frame for any function call, it doesn't have to be `system()`. However most exploits will aim for a shell if possible. The `fake_ret` address is simply where the execution will return to after the `system()` call. If you just put `\x41\x41\x41\x41` there it will segfault. If you point it at `exit()` it will gracefully exit, or you could point it at a number of `pop register` followed by a ret to control execution down the stack (ROP).

Comment: As per your statement `If you just put \x41\x41\x41\x41 there it will segfault` > am I correct to conclude that >> If we simply use `exit()`, then the value of `fake_ret` does not matters in this case.

Comment: Fake_ret would have to be the address of exit, so yes the value matters if you don't want a segfault

Comment: Ok...so the case here is different than a simple buffer overflow with `shellcode`, where we can directly use `exit()` in our shellcode...I guess that's why `fake_ret` does not come into picture there, thanks.